# How to show images to RecycleView using Glide?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have Sqlite database for images but it just store URL only and i want glide to process that URL to show the images ,

Case : I need to show images **url** from sqlite to recycleview using glide .

Iam using this code because it makes me think simply than parsing data to from byte to image or whatever it is.

Please help , now i got error "Java.lang.nullPointerException"

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    private List<Produk> listList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListAdapter(List<Produk> listList){

        this.listList = listList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_list ,parent, false);

        ListViewHolder ListViewHolder = new ListViewHolder(view);
        return ListViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txt_rKode.setText((listList.get(position).getKd_produk()));
        holder.txt_rNama.setText(listList.get(position).getNama_produk());
        holder.txt_rMerk.setText(listList.get(position).getMerk_produk());
        holder.txt_rJenis.setText(listList.get(position).getJenis_produk());
        holder.txt_rVariasi.setText(listList.get(position).getVariasi_produk());
        holder.txt_rFoto2.setText(listList.get(position).getFoto_produk());

        String currentUrl = listList.get(position).getFoto_produk();

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(currentUrl)
                .into(holder.iv_rFoto);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listList.size();
    }

    public Produk getItem(int Position) {
        return listList.get(Position);
    }
```

**ERROR LOG**

And Here it is , the Error log .

```
01-31 14:49:58.795 12577-12577/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: ptacs.ekatalog.com.e_katalogproduk, PID: 12577
   java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).
       at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:665)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:697)
       at ptacs.ekatalog.com.e_katalogproduk.adapter.ListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:56)
       at ptacs.ekatalog.com.e_katalogproduk.adapter.ListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:23)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:610)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
       at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
       at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
    at android.view.View
```

Comment: Please post also the error log

Comment: Please post your stack trace

Comment: done , can you explain that error.

Comment: your context is null. You don't pass context to your Adapter

Comment: please add your **image url** and **activity or fragment** here.

Answer (score 2):

I think `this.mContext = mContext;` is questionable，maybe `mContext` is `null`,so you can write this

```
public ListAdapter(List<Produk> listList,Context mContext){
        this.listList = listList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
```

to confirm `mContext`

Comment: it gives me new error , at activity_list.xml


`error: constructor ListAdapter in class ListAdapter cannot be applied to given types;`

`required: List<Produk>,Context
found: List<Produk>`

`reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length `

Comment: @MostoDani, that is because you have to pass context as 2nd parameter, as declared in method.

Comment: you need to pass the `context`  from outside , just like this `new ListAdapter(list,this)` or `new ListAdapter(list,getActivity())` Decide whether you are in activity or fragment. you can try it .Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for glide.

```
//Glide to load images from url 
if(currentUrl!=null) { 

    //Check whether the url is null   
    Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(currentUrl)//Pass url to be appended
        .asBitmap()
        .fitCenter()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_dummy_user))
        .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_dummy_user))
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmapp, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                mMarkerImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Try editing the comments when copy pasting someone else' answer

Answer (score 0):

First In your `onCreateViewHolder`, Fix this Line:

```js
ListViewHolder ListViewHolder = new ListViewHolder(view);
return ListViewHolder;
```

TO:

```js
return new ListViewHolder(view);
```

Then In `onBindViewHolder` get the URI like below:

```js
String currentUrl = listList.get(position).getFoto_produk();

Uri uri = Uri.Parse(currentUrl);

Glide.with(mContext).load(uri).into(holder.iv_rFoto);
```

Hope this Helps, Also Check if your `getFoto_produk` String value is correct.
You are gonna want the value of this string determined before you Set Adapter to your recyclerview

Comment: yeah dude this is wrong: ListViewHolder ListViewHolder = new ListViewHolder(view);

Comment: it doesnt make any changes, same error . I already check string output with Txt_rFoto and it show up the url and disable the Imageview . after ill initialize the Imageview the app crash and return to parent activity

Comment: Ok, The Problem Is In You Fragment. Check if You used "getActivity()" Before the "view" in Your Fragment

Comment: You know What, Upload Your Fragment Too. If you can't find the Problem

Comment: I didn't use a fragment .

Answer (score 0):

Because of your mContext is null u need pass your context to Adapter class 
 Normally adapter class is pure java class there is no context.

Whenever you call Adapter you must pass ur context from Fragment or Activity.

First, initialize like this in your adapter.

```
public ListAdapter(List<Produk> listList, Context mContext){
    this.listList = listList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

if you call adapter from Fragment then do like this

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(listList, getActivity());
```

if you call adapter from activity then do like this

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(listList, YourActivity.this);
```

that's all good luck anything just let me know.

Comment: **not crash but new problem :D .**

Load failed for www.ellenmacarthurfoundation.org/assets/images/ce100/Phillips-logo.jpg with size [250x250]
                                                                           class                                                                            java.io.FileNotFoundException(/www.ellenmacarthurfoundation.org/assets/images/ce100/Phillips-logo.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))

Comment: i did't get your please post details, attach error log. I think  context issue fixed now your facing another issue right then post your issue properly.

Comment: please test with testing image url first use this first  [http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg]